# Find the coordinate vector from a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find the coordinate vector of $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}$ relative to the following basis of $P_3$:
$$B=\{1-x,1+x,x^{2}-x^{3},x^{2}+x^{3}\}$$

I have never to deal with something more than the standard basis and am really just confused on the approach to this problem. Can't understand my professor and my textbook is not the biggest help either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try solving: $[1+x+x^2+x^3]_B=b_1\cdot(1-x)+b_2\cdot(1+x)+b_3\cdot(x^2-x^3)+b_4\cdot(x^2+x^3)$. The vector $(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$ is almost your coordinates vector- it is actually the coefficiants of the polynomial which itself is the coor. vector

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You have to find $$a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$$ such that:

$$a(1-x)+b(1+x)+c(x^2-x^3)+d(x^2+x^3)=1+x+x^2+x^3$$

Comment: from that given equation, would you set up a coefficient matrix?

Comment: You can simply expand the terms on LHS and set equals with the coefficent of RHS. EG a+b=1.

Comment: You find a system of equation in the unknowns a,b,c,d which are the vector coefficient for the given basis.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

**b<sub>1</sub>** = 1-x

**b<sub>2</sub>**  = 1+x

**b<sub>3</sub>**  = x<sup>2</sup>-x<sup>3</sup>

**b<sub>4</sub>**  = x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>3</sup>

The you need c<sub>1</sub>,c<sub>2</sub>,c<sub>3</sub>,c<sub>4</sub> such that 
c<sub>1</sub>**b<sub>1</sub>**+c<sub>2</sub>**b<sub>2</sub>**+c<sub>3</sub>**b<sub>3</sub>**+c<sub>4</sub>**b<sub>4</sub>** = 1+x+x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>3</sup>

Note that you can rewrite B as

**b<sub>1</sub>** = 1-1x+0x<sup>2</sup>-0x<sup>3</sup>

**b<sub>2</sub>**  = 1+1x+0x<sup>2</sup>-0x<sup>3</sup>

**b<sub>3</sub>**  = 0+0x+1x<sup>2</sup>-1x<sup>3</sup>

**b<sub>4</sub>**  = 0+0+1x<sup>2</sup>1+x<sup>3</sup>

You also have the target vector

**v**=1+x+x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>3</sup>

Each of these can be written in column vector form by taking the coefficients, e.g.

**b<sub>1</sub>** = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

If we write all of the **b** vectors as column vectors and arrange them left to right, we can get a matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\-1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

We can then use that matrix to represent B. I'll use bold to indicate that it's a matrix, i.e. **B** (bolded) represents the basis B (unbolded).

So now if we have a set of coefficients

c<sub>1</sub>**b<sub>1</sub>**+c<sub>2</sub>**b<sub>2</sub>**+c<sub>3</sub>**b<sub>3</sub>**+c<sub>4</sub>**b<sub>4</sub>**

Then we can represent all of the c's with another vecotr:

**c** = $\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4\end{bmatrix}$

Now the problem can be stated succinctly as:

Find **c** such that **Bc** = **v**

Comment: using this, I found c = (0,1,0,1). Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, you can check it by multiplying the first vector by 0, the second by 1, third by 0, and fourth by 1, and adding those together.